# Enum case 'fromPost' not found in type 'Destiny?' in Travis, but the type is declared in File

Tags: swift, xcode, travis-ci, fastlane, pbxproj

I declare type of Enum

```swift
public enum Destiny {
    case fromTrail
    case fromPost
}
```

And use in another part of code, like that:

```swift
 convenience init(withDestinySearch from: Destiny) {
        self.init(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        destinySearch = from
    }
```

But this error appear in build of Travis, and just in Travis CI:  Sigma/Sigma/App/Features/Search/Controller/SearchController.swift:92:15: enum case 'fromPost' not found in type 'Destiny?'

This is build: https://travis-ci.org/ViniciusDeep/Sigma/builds/604199159?utm_source=github_status&utm_medium=notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is that `destinySearch` is an optional, so it's actually expecting:

```
case .fromPost?:
```

instead of:

```
case .fromPost:
```

Or you may unwrap it before, or you can declare the `destinySearch` as implicitly unwrapped value.

About Travis; it could be about the fact that it's using Xcode 10.3, because I can  compile/run it successfully in my own Xcode (11.0).